# how to modify status property of a folder?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, attributes, files-folders

In a specific folder on my PC, I have a folder that contains a specific folder for each project that I have.

The projects are named beginning with date in ISO format.

```
Example: 2019-10-05.MobileViking.Invoice
```

I'm interesting to add a status do each project so I can quickly see if a project is OPEN, CLOSED, RUNNING or ABORTED.

So, in `File Explorer`, I have right clicked on header table which contains columns as `Name`, `Created Date`, `Size` to add a predefined column named `Status`.

Now, is it possible to initialize this column for a folder ?

If yes, how ?

I expect that after right clicking on folder, I have the possibilities to define in `Status` field that project is `Closed` or `Open`.

Answer (score 1):

The Status column is part of Microsoft OneDrive integration, and is used for its purposes. it reflects the synchronization status of the file, so the options are preprogrammed.

- synched (it exists on the local system and in the cloud)
- Cloud-Only (it exists in the cloud but not the local system)
- Local-Only (it exists on the local system but has not been synched to the cloud)
- and more here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-do-the-onedrive-icons-mean-11143026-8000-44f8-aaa9-67c985aa49b3?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

You will not be able to use this column for your custom purpose.

you may be able to use the Comment column, but that means you need to update it in the files metadata. see here for more info https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/68873-how-do-i-add-text-under-comment-column-file-explorer.html

Comment: I think that you have right. It is impossible even using Desktop.INI file. The only possiblity is to write direclty this functionnality in Open Source explorer as Explorer++ or other.